# FeatureActivated event receiver not called for sandboxed feature

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sandbox-solution

I have a sandbox feature, and I've added two event receivers - FeatureActivated and FeatureInstalled. The FeatureInstalled event handler executes, if I attach to the SPUCWorkerProcess and the SPUCHostProcess I can debug the code. However, my breakpoints in the FeatureActivated code are not hit. Also, though in the project properties I have selected the No activation option, in the Solution gallery the feature is always activated.

How can I debug the FeatureActivated event handler in a sandboxed solution? I've also tried Debugger.Break, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Features don't go in the Solution gallery, only solutions do. You need to attach to all of the w3wp processes and the SPUCWorkerProcesses then go to Site settings -> site features and manually activate. It should hit your breakpoint then.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of options:

- Use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` to launch the debugger irrespective of where the feature is activated.
- Use DebugView and use `Debug.WriteLine()` to write debug statements.

Comment: Can you explain the issues you faced

Comment: I am not even sure that the code in my event handler is executing. Debugger.Break() and Debugger.Launch() do not trigger the VS debugger dialog. The breakpoints in the Installed / Uninstalled event handlers work as expected.

Comment: If you select No Activation. It won't be called. Just because it shows "Activated" doesn't mean that it will be activated everytime you install the solution.